# acf and pacf inconsistency in the estimation their first value

Tags: r, time-series

The estimation of the first value of acf and pacf should be the same. Look at *Time Series Analysis, Univariate and Multivariate Methods* of William Wei at page 24.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RITFz.jpg)

However, the acf() and pacf() functions, in R, don't have the same first element. As an example

```
n <- 100
e <- rnorm (n, sd=2.25^2)  # Example 8.2.1 from Brockwell and Davies (1991)
x <- double (n)
x[1] <- 0
x[2] <- 0
for (i in 3:n)
{
  x[i] <- 0.5*x[i-1]+0.2*x[i-2]+e[i]
}
x <- window(ts(x),start=0)
plot (x)
acf (x, lag.max = 40, type = c( "correlation"), ylim=range(-1,1))
pacf (x, lag.max = 40, type="o", ylim=range(-1,1))
```

I did other simulations, and the same problem appears. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the pacf Shows you the first lag, so at t=1 while the acf also includes the value at t=0 (which is obviously 1). Just at them into variables like down below and you'll see it.

```
ac <- acf(x)
ac
pac <- pacf(x)
pac

ac$acf[2]-pac$acf[1]
```

Greetings,

Nick